# Is there a Java equivalent of C#'s LINQ "Select" function

Tags: java, c#, linq, java-stream

LINQ has [Enuemerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0), does Java have any equivalent?

Say I have some class *Record* with three fields *id*, *price*, *itemsSold* and a list of these records from which I want to filter out the most popular item measured by which product sold the most items.

In LINQ I could do something like this

```
var mostPopularItem = records.GroupBy(sr => sr.Id)
       .Select(g => new
       {
           Id = g.Key,
           TotalSold = g.Sum(r => r.ItemsSold)
       })
       .OrderByDescending(i => i.TotalSold).First();
```

by using the `Select(...)` method to reconstruct into a suitable form. How would I do the same in Java? I could simply use streams to extract the actual number

```
records.stream().map(r -> r.getItemsSold()).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList)).get(0)
```

but this would only give me an array of the items sold sorted in descending order. Optimally I would like to end up with an object that contains the *id* and the *itemsSold*.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of `Select` in Java is the `map`-function on `Stream`. But in your case, you probably want to use the second parameter of `groupingBy`-collector to sum up the `ItemsSold`-values.

Java doesn't have is anonymous objects, like you create in your `Select`-call. So you would need to define a class or record to hold that data.

Using records, you could do this:

```java
record TotalSoldRecord(String id, int totalSold) {}

var mostPopularItem = records.stream()
    // Grouping by ID into a Map<String, int>, where the keys are 
    // the recordIds and the values are the sum of "itemsSold".
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getId, 
        Collectors.summingInt(Record::getItemsSold)))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> new TotalSoldRecord(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    // Finding the TotalSoldRecord with the maximum totalSold.
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(TotalSoldRecord::totalSold));
```

Note: You could also use `Map.Entry` as the result instead of mapping it to `TotalSoldRecord`.

Answer (score 0):

This should return the most popular item:

```
var itemsSoldById = records.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(rec -> rec.getId(), summingInt(rec -> rec.getItemsSold())));

var mostPopularItem = itemsSoldById
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalStateException("The list of records is empty"));
```

Previous version before my edit that did not group records by id:

```
   var mostPopularItem = records.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(rec -> rec.getItemsSold()))
        .reduce((rec1 , rec2) -> rec1.getItemsSold() > rec2.getItemsSold() ? rec1 : rec2)
        .orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalStateException("The list of records is empty"));
```

Comment: This doesn't calculate the sum of `itemsSold` per record-ID.

Comment: @marstran you are right, I fixed it so the itemsSold are summed per id

Comment: In your old snippet, the `sorted` step was entirely pointless. The `reduce` operation does already return the element with the highest `getItemsSold()` value, without depending on the order.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
package example.stackoverflow;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Select {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        record Thing(String id, int price, int itemsSold){}
        List<Thing> records = List.of(
                new Thing("a", 5, 14),
                new Thing("b", 4, 33),
                new Thing("c", 6, 10),
                new Thing("a", 5, 21),
                new Thing("c", 6, 12)
        );
        record PopularThing(String id, int totalSold){}
        records.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Thing::id, Collectors.summingInt(Thing::itemsSold)))
                .entrySet().stream().map(e -> new PopularThing(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .max((a,b) -> a.totalSold - b.totalSold)
                .ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't calculate the sum of `itemsSold` per record-ID.

Answer (score 0):

```java
        List<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<>();
        recordList.add(new Record(1L, new BigDecimal(2), 4));
        recordList.add(new Record(1L, new BigDecimal(2), 5));
        recordList.add(new Record(1L, new BigDecimal(2), 7));
        recordList.add(new Record(2L, new BigDecimal(2), 10));

        Map.Entry<Long, Integer> mostPopularItem = recordList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Record::getId, summingInt(Record::getItemsSold))).entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).orElse(null);
```

Output:

```
Key = 1, Value = 16
```

```java
public class Record {
    public Record(Long id, BigDecimal price, Integer itemsSold) {
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
        this.itemsSold = itemsSold;
    }
    private Long id;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Integer itemsSold;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Integer getItemsSold() {
        return itemsSold;
    }

    public void setItemsSold(Integer itemsSold) {
        this.itemsSold = itemsSold;
    }
}
```